# How to compare an element to another element in a different row and different column in r

Tags: r, list, dataframe, compare, lag

I have a large set of data which I have split into a list. Below is a small sample from one of the list elements:

```
>tes
      Bike CheckoutKioskName  Checkout_date_time ReturnKioskName    Return_date_time
24627    1       67th & Pine 2013-03-12 17:54:22            Shop 2013-03-12 20:32:40
24847    1    67th & Frances 2013-05-17 10:31:44  67th & Frances 2013-05-17 10:51:53
24852    1    67th & Frances 2013-05-18 09:27:13  Aksarben Drive 2013-05-18 10:05:29
24864    1    Aksarben Drive 2013-05-18 10:47:13  Aksarben Drive 2013-05-18 10:52:24
24998    1    Aksarben Drive 2013-06-05 19:48:05  67th & Frances 2013-06-26 17:06:52
25434    1    67th & Frances 2013-06-26 19:10:28  67th & Frances 2013-06-26 20:08:09
```

I want to compare the `ReturnKioskName` to the next rows `CheckoutKioskName` and if they do not match I want two flag those two rows and place them into a new data frame. I have tried to do this a few different ways and would like to avoid creating a new data frame initially just to move the `ReturnKioskName` down. I have tried using:

```
tes <- tes[tes$CheckoutKioskName != lag(tes$ReturnKioskName),]
```

But this not giving me the output that I would like. The preferred output should look like this:

```
24627    1       67th & Pine 2013-03-12 17:54:22            Shop 2013-03-12 20:32:40
24847    1    67th & Frances 2013-05-17 10:31:44  67th & Frances 2013-05-17 10:51:53
```

That should be it in this small example because that is the only time they do not match. I plan to use this process to create a giant list of these instances after I run it through each element of my big list ('fz').

I thank you advance for any help you can provide.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I first want to thank everyone for all the ideas and taking your time to reply to my problem. Using ideas from everyone I was able to solve the problem with this code:

```
mismatch <- tes[tes$CheckoutKioskName[-1] != tes$ReturnKioskName & tes$co != nrow(tes),'co']
mismatch.pairs <- c(mismatch, mismatch +1)
tes[tes$co %in% mismatch.pairs,]
```

Answer (score 1):

We can use `base R` to compare the previous value with the current one in the two columns, by removing the first observation and last observation in those columns, compare, append with TRUE (as the length is one less than the number of elements in the column) and use that to subset the rows of 'tes'.

```
tes[with(tes, c(TRUE, CheckoutKioskName[-1]   != ReturnKioskName[-nrow(tes)])),]
#      Bike CheckoutKioskName  Checkout_date_time ReturnKioskName    Return_date_time
#24627    1       67th & Pine 2013-03-12 17:54:22            Shop 2013-03-12 20:32:40
#24847    1    67th & Frances 2013-05-17 10:31:44  67th & Frances 2013-05-17 10:51:53
```

---

The reason `lag` (from `dplyr` didn't work) is because the `default` option is `NA`, if we change the `default`, it could work.

```
tes[with(tes, CheckoutKioskName   != lag(ReturnKioskName, 
                                default = ReturnKioskName[1])),]
#      Bike CheckoutKioskName  Checkout_date_time ReturnKioskName    Return_date_time
# 24627    1       67th & Pine 2013-03-12 17:54:22            Shop 2013-03-12 20:32:40
# 24847    1    67th & Frances 2013-05-17 10:31:44  67th & Frances 2013-05-17 10:51:53
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this is working for the entire data frame. I have a single list element I am testing this on before I run it through the entire list. I used your code above on the df but before I did I created a new column keeping the row count. If the code works correctly I should see column numbers in successive pairs (i.e. 1&2 then 21&22 so on..) but this not what happened.

```
        Bike              CheckoutKioskName                ReturnKioskName  Checkout_date_time    Return_date_time  co
24627    1                    67th & Pine                           Shop 2013-03-12 17:54:22 2013-03-12 20:32:40   1
24847    1                 67th & Frances                 67th & Frances 2013-05-17 10:31:44 2013-05-17 10:51:53   2
23075    1   Bob Kerrey Pedestrian Bridge                  13th & Howard 2014-10-15 11:22:33 2014-10-15 12:04:43  91
23212    1                  13th & Howard   Bob Kerrey Pedestrian Bridge 2014-10-21 13:35:50 2014-10-21 13:49:21  95
23370    1   Bob Kerrey Pedestrian Bridge                  13th & Howard 2014-10-28 12:49:42 2014-10-28 23:05:05 119
23379    1                  13th & Howard   Bob Kerrey Pedestrian Bridge 2014-10-30 09:50:55 2014-10-30 10:06:10 121
23686    1   Bob Kerrey Pedestrian Bridge Tom Hanafan River's Edge Park  2014-11-22 15:16:46 2014-11-22 16:57:24 131
23723    1 Tom Hanafan River's Edge Park           Lewis & Clark Landing 2014-11-28 13:54:32 2014-11-28 15:10:35 133
23750    1          Lewis & Clark Landing Tom Hanafan River's Edge Park  2014-11-29 14:06:20 2014-11-29 14:20:03 135
23753    1 Tom Hanafan River's Edge Park    Bob Kerrey Pedestrian Bridge 2014-11-29 14:28:02 2014-11-29 14:48:28 139
7014     1          Lewis & Clark Landing          Lewis & Clark Landing 2015-06-02 17:52:41 2015-06-02 19:32:31 154
```

If you look at the far 'co' column you can see the pairs are not successive. I am not sure why I am getting such different pairings.

@akrun do you have an idea of what could be going on?

Comment: Also the lag code didn't work and it actually gave a much different output then the base r version.

Comment: Can you provide minimal input that produces the incorrect output with the provided solution, it will be easier to troubleshoot.  You could use `dput` on the small data set and paste the results.  This will make it quicker to analyze.

Comment: I guess this should be an edit on your question and not an answer.  I was using your example and it is giving the expected output.

Comment: Did you loaded the `dplyr` package as there is a `base R` lag as well.

Comment: I didn't load    dplyr which is a mistake on my part but this didn't solve the problem. I should maybe explain why I want the rows in pairs. I am going to end up writing some code to produce a "filler" data entry because each time the `CheckoutKioskName` doesn't match the previous `ReturnKioskName` the bike magically jumped stations (due to a balancing act). I want to identify this jumps so I can create a dummy trip to fill in the gaps in the bikes history. I wanted pairs so I could try to average the time between trips.

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking to keep both rows from an unmatched pair? In this case, first get the indices corresponding to the first element of a mismatched pair:

```
mismatch <- which(test$CheckoutKioskName[-1] != test$ReturnKioskName[-nrow(tes)])
```

then extract those rows and the following ones:

```
tes[sort(c(mismatch, mismatch + 1)), ]
```

Comment: That is giving me an extremely weird output.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a little bigger set of data:

```
> so
       Bike            CheckoutKioskName              ReturnKioskName  Checkout_date_time    Return_date_time  co
557      1 Bob Kerrey Pedestrian Bridge                13th & Howard 2014-10-15 11:22:33 2014-10-15 12:04:43  90
23075    1 Bob Kerrey Pedestrian Bridge                13th & Howard 2014-10-15 11:22:33 2014-10-15 12:04:43  91
612      1                13th & Howard                13th & Howard 2014-10-18 14:17:45 2014-10-18 15:37:54  92
23130    1                13th & Howard                13th & Howard 2014-10-18 14:17:45 2014-10-18 15:37:54  93
694      1                13th & Howard Bob Kerrey Pedestrian Bridge 2014-10-21 13:35:50 2014-10-21 13:49:21  94
23212    1                13th & Howard Bob Kerrey Pedestrian Bridge 2014-10-21 13:35:50 2014-10-21 13:49:21  95
702      1 Bob Kerrey Pedestrian Bridge Bob Kerrey Pedestrian Bridge 2014-10-21 17:21:00 2014-10-21 17:23:21  96
23220    1 Bob Kerrey Pedestrian Bridge Bob Kerrey Pedestrian Bridge 2014-10-21 17:21:00 2014-10-21 17:23:21  97
722      1 Bob Kerrey Pedestrian Bridge Bob Kerrey Pedestrian Bridge 2014-10-23 16:38:25 2014-10-23 17:30:54  98
23240    1 Bob Kerrey Pedestrian Bridge Bob Kerrey Pedestrian Bridge 2014-10-23 16:38:25 2014-10-23 17:30:54  99
729      1 Bob Kerrey Pedestrian Bridge Bob Kerrey Pedestrian Bridge 2014-10-23 21:53:14 2014-10-23 22:25:21 100
```

Looking at this subset if I am successful I should get two pairs which should be:

```
       Bike            CheckoutKioskName              ReturnKioskName  Checkout_date_time    Return_date_time  co
557      1 Bob Kerrey Pedestrian Bridge                13th & Howard 2014-10-15 11:22:33 2014-10-15 12:04:43  90
23075    1 Bob Kerrey Pedestrian Bridge                13th & Howard 2014-10-15 11:22:33 2014-10-15 12:04:43  91
694      1                13th & Howard Bob Kerrey Pedestrian Bridge 2014-10-21 13:35:50 2014-10-21 13:49:21  94
23212    1                13th & Howard Bob Kerrey Pedestrian Bridge 2014-10-21 13:35:50 2014-10-21 13:49:21  95
```

But when I run:

```
so[with(so, c(TRUE, CheckoutKioskName[-1]   != ReturnKioskName[-nrow(so)])),]
```

I get:

```
       Bike            CheckoutKioskName              ReturnKioskName  Checkout_date_time    Return_date_time co
557      1 Bob Kerrey Pedestrian Bridge                13th & Howard 2014-10-15 11:22:33 2014-10-15 12:04:43 90
23075    1 Bob Kerrey Pedestrian Bridge                13th & Howard 2014-10-15 11:22:33 2014-10-15 12:04:43 91
23212    1                13th & Howard Bob Kerrey Pedestrian Bridge 2014-10-21 13:35:50 2014-10-21 13:49:21 95
```

I am starting to wonder if it would be easier just to do a simple comparison to get the row where the `ReturnKioskName` doesn't match the next `CheckoutKioskName` using:

```
tes[tes$CheckoutKioskName[-1] != tes$ReturnKioskName,]
```

Then write an add on to pair the output of each row with the next row in the `df`. Because if I run this code I get:

```
     Bike            CheckoutKioskName              ReturnKioskName  Checkout_date_time    Return_date_time co
557    1 Bob Kerrey Pedestrian Bridge                13th & Howard 2014-10-15 11:22:33 2014-10-15 12:04:43 90
694    1                13th & Howard Bob Kerrey Pedestrian Bridge 2014-10-21 13:35:50 2014-10-21 13:49:21 94
```

Then I just need to figure out how to add the successive row.